# Plugins not rendering after page submit

Tags: jquery

Hi I am initialising several jquery plugins on my page in the document.ready function as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  

    /* Date Picker */
    $('#FromDate').Zebra_DatePicker({
        offset:[-600, 150],
        format:'<?php echo $OrisHandler->__SYSTEM_DATE_FORMAT_NOS ?>'
    });   

    ... other plugins ...    

});
```

Problems is once this page is submitted, the plugins are not rendered like when the page was first accessed. I have tried to put the code to render the plugins in a function outside document ready and then call it as a parameter for document ready. That function fires all the time the page is reloaded but now the plugins are not being rendered?? Maybe something to do with the DOM structure. Any suggestions anyone